# Css is not loading correctly when I follow a link

Tags: css, html

I have an issue with my css.

On the homepage it loads up fine but when I go to a link on my site the css does not load correctly. So basically the below code works fine on index.html but when I go to any link indicated below it craps out.

All of the links have the exact same code so I dont understand why it does not function.

Here is my source code:

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <LINK href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id ="leftcol">
                <a href="content/practice.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Practice!</div></a>
                <a href="content/AboutUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">About Us!</div></a>
                <a href="content/contactUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Contact Us!</div></a>
            </div>
        <div id="left-placeholder"></div>
        <div id ="left-pusher"></div>
        <div id ="content">Math Practice Site <br> hello</div>
    </body>
</html>

//the css file:

/* 
    Document   : styles
    Created on : Nov 2, 2012, 11:50:48 PM
    Author     : me
    Description:
        Purpose of the stylesheet follows.
*/

root { 
    display: block;
}
#leftcol a{text-decoration: none;}
#leftcol{   
    left: 10%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity:0.6;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}
#left-placeholder{
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
}
#left-pusher{
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.left-column-item{
    background: url('images/bgnav.jpg');
    height: 33.334%;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity:0.6;
    color: white;
}
.left-column-item:hover{
    background: url('images/bgnav.jpg');
    height: 33.334%;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
#content{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    float:left;
}

body{
    background: url('images/background.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my practice page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <LINK href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type ="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id ="leftcol">
                <a href="practice.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Practice!</div></a>
                <a href="aboutUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">About Us!</div></a>
                <a href="contactUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Contact Us!</div></a>
            </div>
        <div id="left-placeholder"></div>
        <div id ="left-pusher"></div>
        <div id ="content">Practice!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the html ? Did you include the css in every web page ?

Comment: the html is on the index page and every other page that its linked to. and yes i do. This essentially is the template that im using

Comment: I also think i need to be more specific for some reason the page loads up all white and the items are different sizes. Im running it on my local computer are there any issues with that?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code of AboutUs.html?

Comment: yes, please post your html code.

Comment: hey sorry I was offline I reedited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You css file is not using an absolute path. If your link is within a subfolder on your site, then the css path is no longer correct.

So, assuming your css file is at the root of your site, changing the HTML to the following:

```
<LINK href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

That should fix the issue.

**EDIT**
I know you say everything is fine, but you ARE using relative paths to your CSS, so you could very well have 2 versions of the css file - one that is correct, the other that is not quite the same, and that could account for the "error loading" the css file. You can eliminate this possibility completely by using a root-based path to the location of your proper css file. If anything I'd at *least* start there to control the situation. If there is **still** an issue, then you can at least know you've eliminated this as a possibility - and considering most *every* answer on here is pointing to the same problem, I'd have to say it is the most likely culprit.

Also, your practice page uses

```
<LINK href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

So unless your practice page is in a subfolder in relation to the first page in your post, the two pages are not using the same css file.

Comment: no sorry the css loads fine on the index page. it also loads up on every other page just incorrectly. I think it may have to do with html, body{} tag at the bottom but Im stuck.

Comment: @EugeneScray this proposed solution is in fact the answer, i know it loads fine on your index and not on the others (the others are in subfolders), when you use styles.css in the root and ../styles.css to go up 1 folder, that is called 'relative paths', what jesus.tesh did, was making that 'relative path' into an 'absolute path', so you can use '/styles.css' everywhere, in your index and in your subfolders, it will always try to find your css file from the root of your site. (if you put the css file into a css folder, it would be '/css/styles.css') and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are wrong. For `index.html` it looks for the css in the root dir. When you go to the `content/`, it looks for the css in `content/`.

Use absolute path, or use `../styles.css` for those files in the first-level subdirs.

Comment: no sorry the css loads fine on the index page. it also loads up on every other page just incorrectly. I think it may have to do with html, body{} tag at the bottom of my css but Im stuck.

Comment: That might be true, css should be designed to have more general tags at the top and more specific ones towards the bottom since that's how it loads - bottom rules can override the top ones.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple mistake. When you click a link, it basically goes the 'content' folder and open one of the html file but your css file is in the root folder. So in content folder u need to change the css path of every file.

So, go to content folder

*Replace*

```
 styles.css
```

*with*

```
 ../styles.css
```

Comment: no sorry i thought of that. The page loads up completely white and the size of everything is wrong.

Comment: so the css loads just not correctly.

Answer (score 0):

reason why css is not loading, is that browser cant find it from `content/` folder where your html is.

You can use relative paths in your html files which are in subfolder like this

```
<LINK href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You can also define `base href`, where all your links refer. This might cause other links to act differently, so fix them if needed

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.myawesomesite.com/">
</head>
<LINK href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

with base href set, browsers will always refer that link to www.myawesomesite.com/styles.css no matter where your html file is.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is because you have not used a relative path in you HTML `<link>` tag.

So when your HTML code is invoked in response to the click on your link I expect that it is taking you to another directory and it is no longer able to locate your css.

Relative paths are specified using the ../ notation. This says to the browser look one directory level down from where you are now to locate the file and directory combination specified after the ../

for example consider the following structure:

```
root
  _public
     _admin
         myTest.html
     _css
         myTestStyles.css
```

The link statement in myTest.html would be

```
<link href="../_css/myTestStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

note

../../ says start looking 2 levels down etc.